# Android: how to get an instance of a member field via reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-webview

Here's a fairly convoluted question.  I am trying to access the webviewcore instance member of a webview via reflection.  I want a reference to the webviewcore that is used by my webview, so that i can invoke a method that the webviewcore uses.  I have to do this via reflection because the public sdk does not let you access this class.  I know using reflection to do this is discouraged but i've made my peace with that.

I've read [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/fields.html) that to achieve this i would do something like this:

```
Class  aClass = MyObject.class
Field field = aClass.getField("someField");

MyObject objectInstance = new MyObject();

Object value = field.get(objectInstance);

field.set(objetInstance, value);
```

The problem with doing this (and maybe im misunderstanding this) is that it looks like i have to create a new instance of the WebViewCore to work with and then set it back to my instance.  First and formost, am i understanding this correctly.  If so, then can someone translate the code above to do what i am looking for it to do.  If my understanding is incorrect, does anyone know how else i can access the WebViewCore of an instance of a webview?

Thanks!

EDIT:  Due to confusion i will restate my question.  I have an instance of a webview.  That webview has a member field called 'mWebViewCore' which is an instance of the WebViewCore class. The WebViewCore has a member class called called TextSelectionData.  I need to access the the TextSelectionData object via reflection.  I know how to access fields and methods of the webview through reflection.  So i can get mWebViewCore field, but i don't know how to take that field and access it's fields, methods, classes etc.  The broadstrokes are take an instance of an object, find a specific field in that instance, and access the fields of that field.

Sorry for the confusion.  It come from my weak understanding of reflection, and partially from the fact that i didn't adequately understand WebViewCore class. here's where i've gotten to in the code:

```
Class c = mWebView.getClass();

       try {
            Field webViewCoreField = c.getDeclaredField("mWebViewCore");
            webViewCoreField.setAccessible(true);
            //how do i get the fields of webViewCoreField?
        }
```

Comment: The argument to `Field.get` is the instance from which you're trying to retrieve the specified field. Why would you create a new one? Then you wouldn't get the one set on the instance you care about.

Comment: I see; you're following Jenkiv's tutorial, and misunderstood it: that tutorial creates an instance of the class to retrieve the field from because there isn't an instance yet--you already *have* an instance.

Comment: I have an instance of the webview, not the webviewcore.  I want to access one of the webviewcore's fields.  The webviewcore field is an object itself so i can't just set a value, because the value of that field is an object that i can't instantiate.  I'm sorry if this is confusing.  Could one of you provide some code on how to do this.

Comment: You need to show the object hierarchy/explain what you want better. And you obviously don't want to *set* a field if you're trying to access a field of the "webview", you want to get one. Please describe what you want so people can understand--I still don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: i have added info to the edit i made that should be clearer.  Thank you for helping out.

Comment: If you know how to access the fields of one class, why don't you know how to access the fields of a different class?

Comment: Because i only know how to access the field's of a class if i have an instance.  Unfortunately, i cannot get an instance of the webviewcore, to access it's fields.  I can only get at the webviewcore field.  How do i get the fields of a field?

Comment: ... Once you get the "webviewcore" from the webview, you *have* an instance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11166/discussion-between-aamiri-and-dave-newton)

Comment: I guess my confusion comes from the fact that getDeclaredFields() returns a field object not a WebViewCore object. I've added some code in my question, can you fill in the missing part of my code?

Comment: Right, and using that field you *get* the `WebViewCore` from the instance. Have you looked at the `Field` API at all? Or looked and Jenkov's other tutorials? All this is in there. See answer for working example using made-up classes with private fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a `WebViewCore` with a `private String s` field:

```
public class WebViewCore {
    private String s;
    public WebViewCore(String s) { this.s = s; }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "WebViewCore{" + "s='" + s + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

Assuming a `WebView` with a `private WebViewCore webViewCore` field:

```
public class WebView {
    private WebViewCore webViewCore;
    public WebView() { webViewCore = new WebViewCore("ohai"); }
}
```

Now we reflect:

public class Main {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        // First get the private WebViewCore field...
        Field fWvc = WebView.class.getDeclaredField("webViewCore");
        fWvc.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println(fWvc);

        // Then get an instance of a WebView; you already have one,
        // I'm constructing one...
        WebView wv = new WebView();
        WebViewCore wvc = (WebViewCore) fWvc.get(wv);
        System.out.println(wvc);

        // Now get the private String field from the WebViewCore class...
        Field fS = WebViewCore.class.getDeclaredField("s");
        fS.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println(fS);

        // Now get the value of the private String field from the instance
        // of the WebViewCore we retrieved above...
        String s = (String) fS.get(wvc);
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

So, here's my rant: reflection is a relatively advanced technique, although it's pretty straight-forward. (With the caveat I've been doing this for a really long time, with languages that have better reflective abilities than Java.)

This seems to still be a bit out-of-reach--that being the case, I'd be really, *really* careful about using it, and would avoid it at essentially any cost. I question your need to do whatever it is you're trying to do, and after that, I'd question the *wisdom* of doing whatever it is you're trying to, until stuff like the toy example we're mucking with here causes zero conceptual issues.

Here there be dragons, and they will cook and eat you.

Answer (score 2):

Reflection offers you ability to access private fields, private methods of a class(or rather, an object), and runtime informations.

Your understanding of reflection is correct. But in the code snippet you posted, your use of reflection does not make sense to me. You are setting a value to a field with a value from that field, i.e. you are doing something like:

```
obj.setValue(obj.getValue());
```

You said you wanted to access a private field of WebView, I assume you already have the WebView instance, so once you get the Field reference, you just set the value of that field on your original WebView instance, you **don't** and **shouldn't** create a new WebView object, because it was the original WebView object that you wanted to operate on.

Something like this:

```
WebView myWebView = ...;
Object myValueToSet = ...; 
Class webViewClass = WebView.class
Field field = webViewClass.getField("someField");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(myWebView, myValueToSet);
```